# Load resource outside of a jar applet

Tags: java, localization, jar, applet, webdeploy

I'm working with an applet that loads a resource file .properties for translation purposes, I am packing the applet in a jar file that also include the resource file inside. Already in the website, the applet works by loading the resource file from the jar file, but what I like to do is make the applet to load this file not from the jar but from an external path that is some where in the server, in this way the file can be edited without having to repackage the applet every time a change is neaded. The version of java I'm working is 1.7.0_01

Answer (score 2):

```
URL url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "../properties.prop");
```

Alternately..

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "properties.prop");
```

See [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) & [Applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) docs for the details of the constructor and methods.